# How should I create a DAG sub-schedule in Airflow?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, airflow

I have a functional Airflow DAG generating and emailing charts, based on settings defined in a multi-dimensional Python dictionary. This DAG runs daily.

However, based on the defined settings, there would be need to sub-schedule separate chart emails.

For example:

- Chart A, emailed every Monday.
- Chart B, emailed every third month.
- Chart C, emailed on the last day of every month.

This would be in itself easy to do with cron, but I can't put any of these schedules as the DAG schedule, and I definitely don't want to create a new DAG for each chart.

My idea is that while the DAG runs daily, it checks each day, which charts should be generated on that given day. Can anyone think of a better way, than to program myself a cron-like scheduling system in Python?